# TFS - http://localhost:8080/Service/v1.0/Registration.asmx fail

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Hello I just installed TFS2010 Beta 2 and Im getting that error when I tryed to connect via remote TeamPrise - Eclipse Plugin, people says me that this problem come with the configuration of the TFS so I want to know what I do wrong if I can connect local but not from a remote client.

When I browse the url provided on the TFS Server, I get the same error 404,

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.21006; ASP.NET Version:4.0.21006.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Martin Woodward's blog post [Connecting to TFS 2010 Beta 2 with Teamprise](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/connecting_to_t.html).  TFS 2010 introduces the concept of "project collections" and defaults to installing at the "/tfs" virtual directory.  These two changes mean the connection URL is in the form of:

```
http://servername:8080/tfs/<projectCollection>
```

Unless you've configured your server otherwise, your team projects are probably in the default project collection (named "DefaultCollection").